# cakephp: check isunique from a controller

Tags: php, cakephp

I  want to check if an email/username is unique from a controller. I wrote model validation for isUnique and it works. But I also want a way to use it in controller. Some thing like

```
$this->User->validates(array('email'=>'someemail@domain.com'));
```

or

```
$this->User->checkunique();
//is this the right way to write a different function again.
```

I know I can use findByEmail from controller and check if it returns empty result set. But I feel that there is a simpler approach or already available way cakephp offers. Please correct me if I am wrong and let me point out the correct approach in this context.

Thanks,
kiran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you had a look at the Cook Book already? There's a nice explanation on how to do it:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation/validating-data-from-the-controller.html

To sum it up. First set the data to validate:

```
$this->User->set($data);
```

Then validate it and pass a list of fields to restrict validation to if neccessary:

```
$this->User->validates(array('fieldList' => array('email')));
```

Whether you wrap this up in a custom model method is totally up to you, though from a [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) point of view it's a good idea to do so.